# how to pass array to NSNotification in swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, alassetlibrary

i have the following code which print the url of updated image

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "assetChange:", name: ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification, object: nil) }


func assetChange(notification: NSNotification){

  if var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo { var url:NSSet = info.objectForKey(ALAssetLibraryUpdatedAssetsKey) as NSSet
      var aurl:NSURL = url.anyObject() as NSURL
        println(aurl)

     }

}
```

this code work fine but it will print only first modified image url,but i want all the list of modified image url(array of modified images) please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're choosing one object from the set when using `url.anyObject()`. Instead you need to get all objects from the set and then iterate through the array. The following code should help you:

```
func assetChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    if var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo { var url:NSSet = info.objectForKey(ALAssetLibraryUpdatedAssetsKey) as NSSet
        var urls: [NSURL] = url.allObjects as [NSURL]
        for singleUrl in urls {
            println(singleUrl)
        }   
    }
}
```